# How can i reload page when i select item from drop down list

Tags: asp.net

I have a project with a drop down and a button to refresh page.

I want to refresh page by selecting item from drop down list without using button to reload query.

Comment: Could you give more detail what you have tried, and/or code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the drop down list's OnSelectedIndexChanged event to check the selected value and call the buttonclick event of the refresh button

Comment: this is my drop down 
@Html.DropDownList("Dep", null, "select item ", new { @class = "form-control" })
but i cant use your advise

Comment: @Alireza Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments. Also such important information needs to be in the question, not in the comments of some answer. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoPostback = true in the details of the dropdown. When the OnSelectedIndexChanged gets fired the page automatically reloads.